# Set location of annotation on string-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I need to add annotations over last three data points on my plot. 
Below list `x2` is used as x-axis which a string list. 
List `x2` is a year-month format converted from list `x1`.

My question is how to adjust the x location of my annotation in string-axis such as `x2`? 
I need to move annotations a bit more left so they can located at the center of their data point.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = ["2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-04-01","2020-05-01",
      "2020-06-01","2020-07-01","2020-08-01","2020-09-01","2020-10-01"]

x2 = ["109-01","109-02","109-03","109-04","109-05","109-06","109-07","109-08","109-09","109-10"]

y = [2288, 2638, 3088, 2684, 3033, 2940, 3634, 3219, 3505, 3223]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,9))

ax.plot(x2, y)

label_x = x2[-3:]
label_y = y[-3:]
for i, txt in enumerate(label_y):
    ax.annotate(txt, (label_x[i], label_y[i]+100))
```

[image: plot_output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from [this tutorial page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html), the `annotate` function should take a `horizontalalignment` property for its text (code from the page linked):

```py
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(3, 1),  xycoords='data',
            xytext=(0.8, 0.95), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top',
            )
```

See also [this page about the text properties](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html).

Meaning you should be able to do something like:

```py
for i, txt in enumerate(label_y):
    ax.annotate(txt, (label_x[i], label_y[i]+100), horizontalalignment='center')
```